# How to solve the issue " Property 'NRO_LIQUIDACION' does not exist on type '{}'." on the debuging procces in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm ready to go deploy on a Angular app. On the debugging process i have this error on each item on the main vector . The app works fine, but i'm dealing with this issue in each item on the vector.

**This is the ERROR:**

ERROR in src\app\wizard\form\stepuno\stepuno.component.html(30,23): : Property 'NRO_LIQUIDACION' does not exist on type '{}'.

We will really apreciete some hand here.

This is the code on  html component.html

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <app-input  doValue="{{ WizardArr.NRO_LIQUIDACION }}" key="NRO_LIQUIDACION"  #appInput
      validateType="number" label="Número de Liquidación:" 
      placeholder="Número de Liquidación"
      (focusout)='getLiquidacion($event)'
      (keydown)="OtaxPush()"
      doMaxLength='12' doMinLength='3' ></app-input>
    </div>
```

And here is the vector on the component.ts

export class StepunoComponent implements OnInit {

```
public val_liquidacion = false;
public doClassValidation = '';
// public doMessageValidation = '';
public formReady = false;
public mal: Boolean = true;

public  WizardArr = {}
private valueDate = {};

public ListadoJuzgados: Array<Select2OptionData>;

public ListadoCargosFirmante2: Array<Select2OptionData>;

constructor(
    private dash: DashboardComponent,
    private store: State,
    public rest: RestServiceStepUno

) { }



ngOnInit() {
    // $('input[key=CARGO_FIRMANTE_1]').attr('readonly',true)
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('wizard') == '[]') {
        sessionStorage.setItem('wizard', JSON.stringify([]))
    }

    sessionStorage.setItem('wizard',
        JSON.stringify(
            this.sanitize(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('wizard')))
            )
        );
    console.log('OnInit Uno wizard: ',JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('wizard')))



    const wizard = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('wizard'));
    this.ListadoJuzgados=this.getJuzgados();
    this.ListadoCargosFirmante2=this.ListadoCargoFirmante2();
    //console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

    //ESTO ES PARA MANTENER LOS VALORES ENTRE CAMPOS
    wizard.forEach((element) => {
        this.WizardArr[Object.keys(element)[0]]  = Object.values(element)[0];
    });

}


public sanitize(obj){
    let lookup2 = [];
    let result = [];

    obj.reverse();

    obj.forEach((item,pos)=>{ 
        //console.log('sanitize', Object.keys(item)[0]);
        if (!lookup2.includes(Object.keys(item)[0])) {
            //console.log('splice ',item,pos);
            //result.splice(pos,1);
            result.push(item);
        }
        lookup2.push(Object.keys(item)[0]);
        console.log('result',result);

    })
    return result;

}


public validateForm(data) {}








public getValid(status) {
}

public ListadoCargoFirmante2(){

    var ArrCargos=[
    { id: '', text: 'Seleccione...', disabled: false },
    { id: 'SECRETARIO', text: 'SECRETARIO' },
    { id: 'PROSECRETARIO', text: 'PROSECRETARIO' }
    ];

    var myArrStr =JSON.stringify(ArrCargos);
    var myArrJson= JSON.parse(myArrStr);
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('wizard') != '[]'){

        const wizard = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('wizard'));
        var i=0;
        wizard.forEach(function () {
            myArrJson.forEach(function (item) {
                if (wizard[i]['CARGO_FIRMANTE_2']== item.id){
                    item.selected='selected';
                }
            });
            i++;
        });}
    return myArrJson;}

public selectedValueJuzgado(valor:any){
    this.wizardPush({'ID_JUZGADO' : valor.value});
    console.log(valor);}}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you've assigned {} to WizardArr, which does not have any property NRO_LIQUIDACION.

To get rid of the issue, you should properly declare the properties of WizardArr. For example:

`WizardArr: {
NRO_LIQUIDACION: string;
}`

Or assign a value with property NRO_LIQUIDACION:

`WizardArr = {
NRO_LIQUIDACION = '';
}`

Declaring WizardArr as being of `any` type as proposed by @Uma will also solve the issue, but you should avoid using `any` declarations whenever possible, as a lot of the benefits of typescript comes from knowing variable types at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

when initializing it `WizzardArr` try to set it to `any` type

`public  WizardArr: any = {}`, otherwise it looks like you need to define an interface to get rid of the error

Comment: Thanks for your anwser.
I made it work in the way you proposed.

Comment: That's great! Do you mind to accept this as the answer? :)